# Change Object Method in another class

Tags: c#

First of all, I'm sorry if it's a duplicate. I don't know the right words to describe my problem.

Is it possible to `change` the `method` of an object to another method in another `class` like this?

```
public Class Controller
{
    void DoAction()
    { // Do something here }
}

public Class TheCaller
{
    Controller c = new Controller();
    TheCaller()
    {
        c.DoAction = AnotherAction; // Replace it with another method
    }
    void AnotherAction()
    { // Do something else here }
}
```

The closest I get was using `Delegate`, but Delegate only accept `static functions`.

Can someone help?

Comment: No, you can't remap `DoAction` unless it was designed to do that at the `Controller` class level. If you have control over the `Controller` class, you could make `DoAction` an `System.Action` (delegate) which can remap it for a specific instance. I'm not sure where you got that a delegate can only accept `static` functions, that isn't the case.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thank you! I never realize that `System.Action` would actually do the trick! Also for the delegate on `static` functions, I tried it like this: `public delegate void DoAction();` but when I tried to assign it to another method it said that it needs to be `static` -- or maybe I mistranslated it... Again, thank you!

Comment: Thats because when you define a delegate like that it only defines the signature for the delegate, it doesn't create an instance of it. If you wanted to have that work, you would have to create a member in your class, like `public DoAction DoActionMethod { get; set; }` which would be an instance of the delegate.